# Change game size in PhaserJS

Tags: phaser-framework

I have a menu that links to basically two different games.  One is a portrait game essentially, tall and skinny, while the other is short and long.  I want my game size to change based on which game I enter, but I can't change it.  The best I've found by browsing the web is to use:
this.scale.setGameSize(width, height);

The problem is, I get a message that setGameSize is not a function.  Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two different games then you would have two different game objects. The size is specified in the constructor for the [game object](https://phaser.io/docs/2.6.2/Phaser.Game.html).

```
var portrait_game  = new Phaser.Game(600, 1200, Phaser.AUTO, 'phaser-example', { preload: preload, create: create, update: update });   
var landscape_game = new Phaser.Game(1200, 600, Phaser.AUTO, 'phaser-example', { preload: preload, create: create, update: update });
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to write some code what "this" refer to you can use

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(width ,height,Phaser.AUTO,"gameContainer")
game.scale.setGameSize(width, height);
```

but make sure to change `game.scale.forcePortrait , game.scale.forceLandscape`